# Opening a file in both write and append mode

Tags: python

I am trying to append some data to a file like below..however this fails when the file doesnt exist..
I tried the following..can anyone provide inputs on opening a file in both write mode so that it creates the file if it doesnt exist and append mode at the same time?

CODE:-

```
c = csv.writer(open("//DATA/loc" + csv_file + ".csv", "ab"))
c.writerow([format_time, icount])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
c = csv.writer(open("//DATA/loc" + csv_file + ".csv", "a+b"))
c.writerow([format_time, icount])
```

instead of

```
c = csv.writer(open("//DATA/loc" + csv_file + ".csv", "ab"))
c.writerow([format_time, icount])
```

Comment: Both works but it's more common that find the + sing in after the mode.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `w+b` mode:

```
c = csv.writer(open("//DATA/loc" + csv_file + ".csv", "w+b"))
```

Comment: does the above also work for appending the file if its already there?

Comment: @all - I want for both writing and appending mode ?write mode so that it creates the file when it doenst exist